# How to find which plugin crashes

Tags: errors, debug

I use wordpress version 3.8.3 and as many times as i tried to update wp the site crashes.
Probably it's due to plugins.
Am trying to find a way to learn which plugin causes this confliction but i don't know completely where should i start,
so can anybody who had the same issue give me a clue or the solution to my problem?

PS: I have more than 136 plugins

Comment: Please try http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress, and update your question with the results.

Comment: Thank you man, i did the specific task an other time but not to update wp version. So if i eliminate the errors to 0 from my site i will can update it to the last version for sure?

Comment: Test it in a local copy of your site. Keep error reporting on when you do that.

Comment: I am thinking of an easier way and i need if it is possible your advice, If i disable the plugins which have these erros and the make the upgrade to WP 4.0 is okay? What do you think?